# Duplicate activerecords associated from one model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I have a Task model, a Ticket model and a Category model.

Category has_many Tasks
Ticket has_many Tasks
Category has_many Tickets
Ticket belongs_to Category
Task belongs_to Ticket
Task belongs_to Category

The Tasks that are associated to a Category are the default Tasks for a Ticket when the Category is linked to a Ticket. So I need the Tasks that are associated to a Category to be duplicated and associated to the Ticket when a Category is selected for the Ticket.

I'm wondering if I can do something like this in my Ticket model:

```
  after_create :duplicate_tasks_to_ticket
  after_update :duplicate_tasks_to_ticket

  def duplicate_tasks_to_ticket
    if self.tasks.blank?
      for task in self.category.tasks.all
        new_task = Task.new
        new_task.name = task.name
        new_task.ticket_id = self.id
        new_task.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Right now this doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you why `new_task.save` is commented out?

Comment: If you are already associating them to the category, why do they need to be associated to the ticket also? If you need the granularity of being tied to a task, then just use that association to get all tickets under a category. Tieing them to both just make site complicated.

Comment: because every time a ticket is created i need to duplicate the tasks from the category and associate them to the ticket. Basically the category has the default tasks for a ticket. A task record is only being associated to either a ticket or a category, but not both.

Comment: woops i accidentally commented it out before i copied it. i changed it above. what i have in my code is not commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already associating them to the category, why do they need to be associated to the ticket also? If you need the granularity of being tied to a ticket, then just use that association to get all tasks under a category. Tieing them to both just make site complicated. Now, if you absolutely need to tie them to both, you should create an assignment table for that, which stores category_id, task_id. Another assignment table for ticket_id, task_id. Then keep the task as one record, as supposed to duplicating data.

Your code looks fine for the most part. I don't think you need the .all at the end. The associations will automatically load all that you are referencing under that model.

Though try using the association build method instead:

```
def duplicate_tasks_to_ticket
  if self.tasks.blank?
    for task in self.category.tasks.all
      self.tasks.build(:name => task.name)
    end
    self.save
  end
end
```

The build creates a new object of that association, assigning the foreign key for you. Then you just call save on the parent model, and it will do all the proper insert statements.

Comment: that worked great and it looks a lot cleaner. I need to be duplicated, and not tied to both category and ticket, because each time a ticket is created with the same category as another ticket i can't someone needs to be able to check it as complete which is an attribute of the task. Otherwise someone would check the task as complete and the task could be completed for all tickets it's assigned too. thanks for making that look much nicer.

Comment: Ah okay, since I don't know the details, that probably makes more sense for your particular use case. One thing, if you want to make sure you handle the saving of the second object correctly, maybe wrap an if statement and execute some sort of logging or notification if the save fails. Another option is to use save! instead, which will throw an exception if the model has validation issues. And you are most welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

Actually dexter I had it commented out when i tried it and it's working now. So I guess what I came up with works just fine. Unless someone knows how I can refine it and make it cleaner. It's working now.